# trying to install `gdb-multiarch` on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: remote-debugging

I am trying to install `gdb-multiarch` on `ubuntu 18.04`. When I use `sudo apt-get install gdb-multiarch`, I am getting following error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gdb-multiarch : Depends: gdb (= 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libpython3.6 (>= 3.6.5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I couldn't find a way to install above dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably caused by an installation of a version of python that wasn't included with your Ubuntu install so your package manager is confused about what to do.

This worked for me:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061762/ubuntu-18-04-cant-upgrade-because-of-libpython3-6-version-conflicts

Comment: Thanks Jimmy!
These steps helped.

`sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa*`

`sudo apt remove libpython3.6-minimal`

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

`sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Reboot the VM and I was able to install `gdb-multiarch`

Answer (score 1):

install the specific version using

`sudo apt install gdb=8.1-0ubuntu3.2`

then install gdb-multiarch

`sudo apt-get install gdb-multiarch`